# What are options to run multiple cloud sql and bigquery queries in a predefined sequence

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to perform a periodic data purge and data load operations between GCP BigQuery and GCP CloudSql.
This involves running multiple queries in GCP BigQuery and GCP cloud SQL in a predetermined sequence and using the query results from earlier queries  in subsequent queries
I am considering a few options as described below

Option1 : Use BigQuery "Scheduled Queries" that uses  "Federated query" (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries). This is good as far job involves trigger "read only" queries in gcp cloud SQL database and run multiple queries in gcp BiqQuery.
However since my operation involves purging data from GCP cloud SQL so federated queries are ruled out.

Options 2: Another option I am considering is to use a gcp compute linux engine VM as my controller for performing operations that span across a gcp cloud SQL mysql database and GCP bigQuery.
I can run a cron job to schedule the operation
As far as running gcp cloud SQL queries from a gcp compute engine VM goes, that is well documented by google in a tutorial "Connect from a VM instance" ( Learn how to connect your Cloud SQL instance from a Compute Engine VM instance)
And , for trigering the gcp Big Query queries,   bq command line tool (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool) provides a good option.
This should allow me to run a sequence of interlaced BigQuery and gcp cloud SQL

Do you see any gotchas in "option 2" described above that I am contemplating.

Is there any other option that you can suggest ?  I wonder if cloud dataflow is an appropriate solution for a task that involves running queries across multiple databases ( cloud SQL and BigQuery in this case) and using the intermediate query results in subsequent queries

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about your option 2, I probably would consider DataFlow, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, as the main backbone for those operations instead of VMs. You might find serverless solutions much cheaper and more reliable depending on your wider context, and "how frequently" the "periodic" process is to run.

On the other hand, if you (or your company) has already relevant experience in "some code" on VM, but no skills, knowledge and experience in the serverless solutions, the "education overhead" can increase the overall cost of this path.

Answer (score 1):

To orchestrate your queries, you need an orchestrator. There are 2 on Google Cloud:

1. The big one Cloud Composer, entreprise grade (feature and cost!)
2. The new one: [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows). Serverless and easy to use

I recommend you to use Cloud Workflows. You can create your workflow of call that you perform to BigQuery (federated queries or not)

If you need to update/delete data in Cloud SQL, I recommend you to create a proxy Cloud Functions (or Cloud Run) that take in parameter a SQL query and execute it on Cloud SQL.

You can call your Cloud FUnctions (or Cloud Run) with Workflow, it's only a HTTP call to perform.

Workflow has also the feature to handle and to propose some processing capacity on the answer gather from your API Calls. So you can parse the response, iterate on it and call the subsequent step, even by injecting some data coming from previous steps.